# Paginate an eager loaded relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 3.x.

`Post::with(
            array('blogs' => function($query) { 
                $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id); 
            } ))->get();`

How can I paginate the posts?

Comment: The easy answer is you can't do it like that. Can you better explain what you are trying to achieve? Are trying to filter posts based on `post->blog->user_id` or are trying to get **all** posts and just eager load the blogs that belong to the user? Each may have a completely different answer :)

Comment: I want to list all posts for a specified blog (blog->user_id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with. A user can have many blogs and a post can belong to many blogs.

```
    /**
    * Get all posts by a user for all blogs.
    * @return paginated posts.
    */
    public static function get_posts_for_user($user_id, $limit)
    {
        return Post::left_join('blog_post', 'posts.id', '=', 'blog_post.post_id')
                ->join('blogs', 'blogs.id', '=', 'blog_post.blog_id')
                ->where('blogs.user_id', '=', $user_id)
                ->paginate($limit);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the feedback above it seems that eager loading isn't what you are looking for. Try this.

```
Post::where( 'user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id )->paginate( 10 );
```

Or you could add a posts method to the User model.

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->has_many( 'Post' );
}
```

Then use that to get the users posts.

```
Auth::user()->posts()->paginate( 10 );
```

Comment: I believe this doesn't answer OP's question. He wants to get all posts made to an user blog(s). And not all posts made by the user.

Answer (score 1):

FakeHeal,

Supposing that `$user->has_one('blog')`, you can simply use Laravel magic relationship getter:

```php
$user = Auth::user();
$user->blog->posts();
```

If that's not the case and `user->has_many('blog')`, you need to use JOIN to retrieve all posts made to all of that user blogs.

```php
$user = Auth::user();
$posts = Posts::join('blogs', 'blogs.id', '=', 'posts.blog_id')
    ->where('blogs.user_id', '=', $user->id)
    ->get('posts.*');
```